# Add character to specific index in string - swift 3

Tags: swift, string, swift3

I'm trying to insert a specific character in a specific index in a string lets say

```
var text = "1234567890"
```

i want that variable to add the country code of the phone number:

```
text = text.replacingCharacters(in: text.startIndex..<text.index(after: text.startIndex), with: "+593\\U00a0")
```

Then i have to format that string into something like this: "+593 23-456-7890", so i have to insert "-" into the index 8 and 11 but i have only found answers with swift 2.0. Strings had a method called insert that doesn't exists anymore. i've tried this:

```
text = text.insert("-", at: text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: +8))
```

but I have the following error "Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'String'

Comment: If my answer was helpful, I would appreciate it if you accept my answer. This will mark this question as "answered" and it will give you, as well as me, some reputation.

Answer (score 10):

Insert operates on the actual string itself. Therefore, there is no need to assign back to it. You can just use the following:

```
text.insert("-", at: text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: +8))
```

More information about inserting into a string can be found in the [Swift documentation from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID496).